# How to Play a Random Sound with NSArray in Cocos2d

Tags: audio, random, cocos2d-iphone, nsarray

I am trying to have a random sound play whenever the user touches the button.  Here is my code so far:

```cpp
-(void) playEffect {    
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1.mp3", "2.mp3", "3.mp3", nil];
    int index;
    index = random() % array.count;
    sound *theSound = [array objectAtIndex:index]; 
    [theSound play];    
}

-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    //Blah, blah, blah

    //PLAY RANDOM SOUND
    [self playEffect];  
}
```

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CocosDenshion for this. Smth like

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect: pathToYourSoundFile];
```